# Looking for name of a novel featuring 7th son of 7th son

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to find the name of a fantasy novel that I read during the 80s. The author I think was a woman (British or American) and the cover featured a man on a horse with some type of headdress with antlers.

The story if I remember correctly was set at Christmas time, a young boy 7th son of a 7th son who seems to slip back and forth into the past and finding ancient paths through the snow around his house and village. Other imagery incluse iron/wood carved circle/cross.

Sorry very vague but would like to read this book again. So any help identifying the book greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE Tom Carter! Glad we were able to answer your question to quickly! Site policy is to mark as a "Duplicate" questions like yours which share an answer with similar questions. I have therefore registered a "close vote" which is the process by which we do this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your memories are spot on! This is almost certainly the 1973 YA novel [*The Dark Is Rising*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Is_Rising) by British novelist [Susan Cooper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Susan_Cooper). The book is the second in the five-novel [*The Dark Is Rising Sequence*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Is_Rising_Sequence).

The story is about a young man named Will—indeed the seventh son of a seventh son—who discovers he belongs to an ancient order of magical beings who exist to protect 'The Light' in an eternal light versus dark struggle. Part of eleven-year old Will's journey involves magical paths and something like the slipping back and forth between then and Will's present which you describe. The circled crosses are both symbols and artifacts relevant to this struggle. The tale occurs during [Yuletide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yule), and Will encounters disparate interpretations of the season's significance (pagan vs. Christian) in the story.

Although there have been many published editions of the book in different formats, the Puffin Books paperback edition featured a Horned King headdress on the cover, much as you describe:

[image: The Dark Is Rising paperback cover published by Puffin Books]